# drupal_goto() not remove url path of 404 page

Tags: views, theming, hooks

I have a search form which returns to search page.

```
drupal_goto('/searchyour/trips', array('query' => $query));
```

this is work fine if a user in active page. search url will replace as eg: example.com/searchyour/trips

But if user in 404 page (example.com/nopage) and click search, search url will set to example.com/nopage/searchyour/trips I want to change this to example.com/searchyour/trips.

I'm new to drupal. Help me to solve this. :-)

Comment: are you sure your drupal_goto and any redirects within your form all specify an absolute and not relative path, eg '/searchyour/trips' not 'searchyour/trips'.

Comment: yep, sure it's relative. because it works for valid page, like example.com/countyrpage is a valid page. In this page  drupal_goto('/searchyour/trips', array('query' => $query)); works fine. (i.e direct to :example.com/searchyour/trips )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7 , you can check whether the page is 404 page or not. If it is a 404 page then change the drupal_goto **$path** parameter.

- [**drupal_get_http_header**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_http_header/7) : Gets the HTTP response headers for the current page.

```
  $status = drupal_get_http_header("status");
  $path = ($status == '404 Not Found'){
    //change the path from example.com/nopage/searchyour/trips to example.com/searchyour/trips
    drupal_goto('/searchyour/trips', array('query' => $query));  
  }else{
    drupal_goto('/searchyour/trips', array('query' => $query));
  }
```

Comment: The thing is if user in 404 not found page that means there will be some values in the url. like example.com/nopage/ what I want is to remove appended value and change to original url (example.com)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the question, there is search link on the page or in header section, which takes the user to 'searchyour/trips' URL. The URL for this link becomes invalid when you are on 404 URL.

I believe you can use [url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) function to make your search link on the page. For example,

url('searchyour/trips')

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. I have solved this problem but it seems it isn't the correct way.

The problem I found here is drupal_goto() function has used GET['destination'] value if the url is not secure (this is what I understand after reading the code). Otherwise it will empty.

```php
  // A destination in $_GET always overrides the function arguments.
  // We do not allow absolute URLs to be passed via $_GET, as this can be an attack vector.

  if (isset($_GET['destination']) && !url_is_external($_GET['destination'])) {
    $destination = drupal_parse_url($_GET['destination']);
    $path = $destination['path'];
    $options['query'] = $destination['query'];
    $options['fragment'] = $destination['fragment'];
  }
```

If it's empty, then search your/trips path used in $path. Otherwise it will override to the $GET['destination']. So if I clear the $GET['destination'], it works.

I doubt this is a good practice. So any comments about it will be appreciated.